# Can't execute any basic command in linux console

Tags: linux, bash

I know how the problem was created, but really have no idea how to restore the server command execution.

The thing is, I was configuring the environment variables of Glassfish in my Ubuntu server, and I modified the `.bashrc` file from root and added an `export` clause (with `GLASSFISH_HOME` variable) and a `PATH` clause (pointing to the `$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin`).

Right after I close the console and open it again so the changes take effect, and (BAM!) once I start the new console session then none of the basic commands (`dir`, `find`, `nano`, `ifconfig`, anything) work now, I can only use `cd` to move in directories, I am trying to edit again the `.bashrc` file to undo the changes but can't edit it either, none of the editors open! In the command line I only get `-bash: dir: command not found`.

Please, if you have any solution for this; I know it seems trivial, but I'm kind of blind without being able to see or find the files and folders where commands/applications are located.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I know it started as a development task but I think is a better match for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: It's **/home/newuser/glassfish3/glassfish/bin**. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do an export of the binary paths:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
```

right after that you're able again to operate and to reverse your changes.

Otherwise just do an edit with your favorite editor while given the full path to your editors binary:

```
/usr/bin/emacs -nw /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: Phew!, thanks bro, that solved the problem. I have control of the server again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You've overwritten your `$PATH`, rather than appending to it, you probably have something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin
```

or similar, but you need to append the current `$PATH` to the end of it:

```
export PATH=$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

To edit this in the terminal, you will have to append `/usr/bin` to your editor (e.g. `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc`) until you correct the problem.

You may wish to [read more about the `$PATH` variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you erased your path when you were changing the environment variables; this will prevent most commands from being found.

Fortunately, you can work around this by using the full path name when specifying the command.

vim doesn't work?  Use /usr/bin/vim

ls doesn't work?  Use /usr/bin/ls

Most command you want to use will be in /usr/bin; if not found there you can check /bin or /usr/sbin

With access to the editor you should be able to fix the startup script to get your path back.

Comment: Hi antlersoft, thanks for your answer, but already tried that. I went to /usr/bin and is like nothing where there except for java. Do you know any other location where vim or nano could be located?

Comment: @JoeAlmore Now that you path is fixed you can find out with `type -a vim`. I would guess /bin.