# Basic Commands in Linux Terminal not working

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I just installed Linux in a VirtualBox VM. I'm learning to code with the Odin Project. They link to Viking Code School for basic tips in Terminal. Some of the commands work but many of the most basic commands do not work for me.

`clear` works fine and so does `sudo`, but other basic commands such as `touch` and `open` and navigating around the directories just do not work for me.

Please help, I know there's something simple I am missing and I would love to progress with my coding learning.

---

[image]

I am a complete beginner. I cannot find anywhere else to ask my question so I come here where you are all vastly more advanced than me. Please excuse the simplicity of my question.

I have looked for a similar question on Stack Overflow and found the following two questions but neither are in fact the same as mine, not really:

- [About basic commands in bash (cp, cd,..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107434/about-basic-commands-in-bash-cp-cd)
- [Can't execute any basic command in linux console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437084/cant-execute-any-basic-command-in-linux-console)

Comment: *"I cannot find anywhere else to ask my question..."* - Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: But I'm learning to program. This question is a about a very fundamental part of programming (I thought). Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no `ipfonfig` on `Linux`, use `ifconfig` instead. And it seems that `mkdir`, `touch`, `cd` work correctly. So what's your problem? BTW you don't need that `$` at the beginning before a command.

Comment: You are touching files to create them, moving directory and then trying to cat out the files. The files won't be in the directory you moved to and hence cat cannot find the files. This is normal behaviour. Verify that touch is working by "touch filename" then checking it is there with "ls filename"